# Jasmine unit testing help for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Hi I need help testing the following Auth javscript:

```
angular.module("vizApp").factory("Auth", function Auth($location, $rootScope, Session, User, $cookieStore) {
    "use strict";
    // Get currentUser from cookie
    $rootScope.currentUser = $cookieStore.get("user") || null;
    $cookieStore.remove("user");

    return {

        /**
         * Authenticate user
         *
         * @param  {Object}   user     - login info
         * @param  {Function} callback - optional
         * @return {Promise}
         */
        login: function (user, callback) {
            var cb = callback || angular.noop;

            return Session.save({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }, function (user) {
                $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                return cb();
            }, function (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }).$promise;
        },
```

This is what I have until now

```
describe('Auth Service:', function(){
describe('Before auth', function(){
    beforeEach(module('vizApp'));
    var service, httpBackend, scope;
    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.inject(function($injector){
            httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            service = $injector.get('Auth');
            scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            spyOn(service, 'login');
            })
        });

    it('current user is Null before user logins', function(){
        expect(scope.currentUser).toEqual(null);
    });

    it('login function exists', function() {
        expect(typeof(service.login)).toEqual('function');
    });

    it('login function has zero calls before user logs in ', function() {

        expect(service.login.callCount).toEqual(0);
    });

});
describe('After auth', function(){
    beforeEach(module('vizApp'));
    var service, httpBackend, scope;
    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.inject(function($injector){
            httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            service = $injector.get('Auth');
            scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            spyOn(service, 'login');
            service.login({
            email: "testingt@test.com",
            password: "testing1"
        });

            })
        });

    it('current user is not null after user logins', function(){
        expect(scope.currentUser).toNotEqual(null);
    });

    it('Login function has one call after user logs in ', function() {
        expect(service.login.callCount).toEqual(1);
    });     
});
});
```

The first sets of tests pass but then when I try running the login function it doesn't work. Am I going about this the wrong way.

I keep getting "Chrome 35.0.1916 (Mac OS X 10.9.2) Auth Service: After auth current user is not null after user logins FAILED
    Expected null to not equal null.
    Error: Expected null to not equal null."

Comment: did you flushBackend or scope digest to let the service.login to actually change the scope values?

Comment: where would I have to flushBackend? after I do
`
             service.login({
            email: "testingt@test.com",
            password: "testing1"
        });

`

Comment: yes, since the login service do a backend call (i suppose)

Comment: What you should be doing here is not flushing the backend, but stubbing the `Session.save` method to test your factory in isolation (right now you have an integration test with the `Session` dependency, not a strict unit test of `Auth`).

Comment: can you explain what you mean a little more @scarlz